# Uploading Excel Datasource folder to SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, excel

I have a folder which contains an Excel data capture real time dashboard and form templates that are linked to the dashboard. How can I upload this folder to SharePoint and still maintain the connectivity?

Comment: Hello KMF, What's the connectivity source?

Comment: Do you want both the locations (sharepoint & your file system) to be in sync?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a sync the Files to a SharePoint document library.

http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2014/10/sync-sharepoint-2013-library-with-local-folder.html